# Infinite recursion aliasing `cd`

Tags: linux, shell, unix, zsh

I want to record my most recent `cd` across any one of my terminals. I thought a good way to do this would be to write a simple bash script wrapping `cd`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $1 && echo `pwd` > /tmp/.cwd
```

Since I want the `cd` to occur in my terminal's process, I need to run the script with `. bettercd.sh`, correct?

Here comes my issue:
If I alias `cd` to this new `. bettercd.sh`, my shell also expands the `cd` inside of the script with the `. bettercd.sh` -- infinite recursion.

Is there any way to call `cd` from a different name but with the same behavior? To put it another way, is there some command that behaves exactly (or very similar to) `cd` that I can use in my shell script without noticing a difference when I use the aliased `cd` day to day?

My shell of choice is zsh, if that's relevant in some way.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I removed the `bash` tag because, if you're using `zsh` for your shell, then `bash(1)` is not involved. But I left it in your script, because that's what you're trying to get to work.

Comment: You cannot make `cd` a script, because it will only affect the shell forked for that script (not the invoking parent shell). You need to use functions for such things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using zsh, you can use `builtin cd` in place of `cd`. This forces the shell to use the builtin command instead of recursively calling your alias.

`builtin` does not exist in standard bourne shell. If you need this to work in other shells, try prefixing cd with a backslash like this: `\cd`. It works to bypass aliases but not shell functions.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about zsh. You mean that it also works in bash :-)

Comment: "If you need this to work in other shells" is a bit vague then.

Comment: Intentionally vague: I meant, if you need compatibility across all bourne-compatible shells. I could have made that clearer.

Comment: Thank you -- this is what I was looking for! 
Note: @sarnold has a very elegant solution for doing some action whenever a directory is changed

Answer (score 6):

`zsh` provides the `chpwd_functions` hook functions specifically for tools like this. If you define a function to append the new directory to a file and add the function to the `chpwd_functions` array, it'll automatically run the routine every time it changed directory -- whether for `pushd` `popd` or `cd`:

```
$ record_pwd() { pwd > /tmp/cwd }
$ chpwd_functions=(record_pwd)   
$ cd /tmp ; cat /tmp/cwd
/tmp
$ cd /etc ; cat /tmp/cwd
/etc
$
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a very elegant way to record the pwd -- I will definitely use this.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your script call `cd` with `builtin`:

```
#!/bin/bash
builtin cd $1 && echo `pwd` > /tmp/.cwd
```

Comment: It should not work, since you cannot make `cd` a script (which would change the directory only of the shell forked to run that script, not of the invoking parent shell).

Comment: The alias OP creates for the script **sources** the script instead of **executing** it. See the question above.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to already posted answers (I personally would prefer @sarnold’s one) you can use the fact that `chdir` in zsh has the same behavior as `cd`, but is not an alias of the kind you can define with `alias` (it may be an “alias” in C source code, I do not know) thus using it is safe.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting `unalias cd` at the top of your `bettercd.sh`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a different name to avoid exactly this happening - what if some other script does a CD - if it uses your version instead of "normal", that could play havock with the system.