# How do I get ZSH to display the current directory in the Terminal frame?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I'm gradually switching from Bash to ZSH, and trying to learn by replicating features. Can't seem to find this one though.

[image: Bash does this by default I think]

What should I put, and where should I put it? Is this even possible? Thanks.

Comment: It is probably set by the shell prompt under `bash` -- what output do you get from `echo $PS1` under `bash`?

Comment: AFAIK, Terminal just *does* this. My $PS1 is just set to the infinity symbol ∞.

Comment: `zsh` provides a [`chpwd_functions`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9865595/377270) array that is significantly nicer than using `PS1`-based or `precmd`-based escapes. I was hoping the `PS1` would have the `Terminal.app` escape sequences for setting the window title. Perhaps it is in `PROMPT_COMMAND`?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. This is all brand new to me. I am looking at https://github.com/holman/dotfiles/tree/master/zsh and wondering if it prompt.zsh might be where this needs to happen. I was wrong as well about the previous link. False positive.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
settitle() { printf "\e]0;$@\a" }
dir_in_title() { settitle $PWD }
chpwd_functions=(dir_in_title)
```

Now, your `cd` commands will run the `dir_in_title` function, which will print an escape sequence that asks `Terminal.app` to update the title. (Oddly enough, using an escape sequence that also works in `urxvt`, at least. These must be more standardized than I expected.)

If you like the effect, you'll need to add these lines to your `~/.zshrc` for it to work on future terminals.

I grabbed the correct escape sequence [from Chris Page on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/79972/set-the-title-of-the-terminal-window-to-the-current-directory/321733#comment368133_79989) and the style of functions [from my answer to similar but different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9865595/377270). [Chris Page gave his own answer on that question with details on OS X 10.7 that are drastically different](https://superuser.com/a/321733/69238). When you upgrade you'll probably want to use his mechanism instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have this function defined. Requires some Python knowledge and is a bit verbose, but I know what's happening there.

Wheres without Googling I don't know why sarnold's `printf "\e]0;$@\a"` does what it's supposed to do.

```
function current_directory()
{
    echo $(python3 -c "from pathlib import Path; print(Path('.').absolute().name)")
}
```