# How do I properly set the title in Terminal using zsh?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I have been trying to set the title of my Terminal appropriately, but I haven't had any success. Currently, it looks like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/645bf21jzziqoi6/Screenshot%202015-04-14%2013.00.10.png?dl=0), and if I were to change directory, to say the desktop, it would become [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4zi36jjy9ilnr0l/Screenshot%202015-04-14%2013.02.50.png?dl=0).

I would prefer if the title only had the current folder and process. I've tried various methods, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11025063/4788416), but to no success.

I'm using the default Terminal app in Yosemite, and am running zsh.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want anything in the window title other than the current directory and process (which is there by default in Terminal.app), you can do the following at the end of your `~/.zshrc`:

```
precmd () {print -Pn "\e]0;\a"}
```

Example:

[image: screenshot]

I'm afraid you can't get rid of that terminal size though since it appears to be hard-coded into Terminal.app (maybe I'm wrong).

For more information, see [How to change the title of an xterm: Examples for different shells](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Xterm-Title-4.html).

---

By the way, I recommend [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/) instead of Terminal.app. The Swiss army knife of terminal emulators, infinitely better then Terminal.app, highly customizable.

Comment: However, I think directory + process + terminal size is the default. I think you're currently doing something in your rc

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll switch to iTerm

Comment: As per https://aheze.medium.com/how-to-change-the-window-title-in-terminal-zsh-oh-my-zsh-ca41f3a35128 , you can change the title from Terminal.app Preferences, one of the boxes you can uncheck is "Dimensions" (to get rid of the size appearing at the end of the title).